# Can we execute multiple insert queries in JDBCIO.write function in single CloudSQL connection with an apache beam pipeline?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I am using `JDBCIO.write()` function of apache beam to write streaming data into cloudSQL. As per my requirement I have to write same data in two different tables.
Actually I am creating two differnt JDBCIO connection to write data in cloudSQL tables.
Is there any way to write two insert queries in single `JDBCIO.write()` function?

```
outputStringPcollection
            .apply("Write to CloudSQL table",
                    JdbcIO.<String> write()
                            .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                                    .create(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME,
                                            URL)
                                    .withUsername(USERNAME)
                                    .withPassword(PASSWORD)
                            .withStatement(insertQueryTable1)
                            .withPreparedStatementSetter(new SetQueryParameter())
                            .withStatement(insertQueryTable2)
                            .withPreparedStatementSetter(new SetQueryParameter()));
```

I tried to execute above code by writing two different insert queries in single JDBC connection but data is inserting in only one table (i.e. Table2).

So, can we execute multiple queries in single connection? If yes, is there any other way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do it in a single connection. The best you can do is:

```
JdbcIO<String> configuredWrite = JdbcIO.<String>.withDataSourceConfiguration(...);

outputStringPcollection.apply(configuredWrite.withStatement(s1)...);

outputStringPcollection.apply(configuredWrite.withStatement(s2)...);
```